# JSF 2.0 + Icefaces 2.0.0 Beta2 and Tomcat 7 failure

Tags: jsf, tomcat, icefaces

I have an existing JSF 2.0 project working on a Tomcat 7.0.4 server. I am trying to add Icefaces 2.0.0 Beta2 to this project. I downloaded the file `ICEfaces-2.0.0-Beta2-bin.zip` from Icefaces official homepage and followed the instructions described [here](http://wiki.icefaces.org/display/ICE/Adding+ICEfaces+to+Your+Application).

I copied the 4 files `icefaces.jar`, `icepush.jar`, `icefaces-ace.jar` and `icefaces-compat.jar` from the `ICEfaces-2.0.0-Beta2-bin/icefaces/lib` directory to the `WEB-INF/lib` directory (the one that I included all my jars). The `jsf-api.jar` and `jsf-impl.jar` was already included in my project so these was not copied.

When I deployed the webapp to the Tomcat 7 server, following error occured:

```
/home/user > ant deploy reload

Buildfile: build.xml

build:

deploy:

reload:
   [reload] FAIL - Encountered exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/wtree-www] has not been started

BUILD FAILED
FAIL - Encountered exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/wtree-www] has not been started

Total time: 0 seconds
```

This is from the `catalina.log`, I think this might be intresting:

```
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
Nov 2, 2010 10:04:42 PM org.icepush.servlet.MainServlet <init>
INFO: 
ICEsoft Technologies Inc.
ICEpush 2.0.0 Beta2
Build number: 13
Revision: 22877

Nov 2, 2010 10:04:43 PM org.icefaces.util.EnvConfig init
INFO: ICEfaces Configuration: 
org.icefaces.render.auto: true [default]
org.icefaces.autoid: true [default]
org.icefaces.aria.enabled: true [default]
org.icefaces.blockUIOnSubmit: false [default]
org.icefaces.compressDOM: false [default]
org.icefaces.compressResources: true [default]
org.icefaces.connectionLostRedirectURI: null [default]
org.icefaces.deltaSubmit: false [default]
org.icefaces.lazyPush: true [default]
org.icefaces.sessionExpiredRedirectURI: null [default]
org.icefaces.standardFormSerialization: false [default]
org.icefaces.strictSessionTimeout: false [default]
org.icefaces.windowScopeExpiration = 1000 [default]  
Nov 2, 2010 10:04:43 PM org.icefaces.impl.renderkit.DOMRenderKit <clinit>
INFO: 
ICEsoft Technologies Inc.
ICEfaces 2.0.0 Beta2
Build number: 003
Revision: 22976

Nov 2, 2010 10:04:43 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager initialize
INFO: Unsanitized stacktrace from failed start...
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: jar:file:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.4/webapps/wtree-www/WEB-INF/lib/icefaces-compat.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Class 'com.icesoft.faces.component.effect.ApplyEffectRenderer' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
 at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:275)
 at com.sun.faces.config.processor.RenderKitConfigProcessor.addRenderers(RenderKitConfigProcessor.java:309)
 at com.sun.faces.config.processor.RenderKitConfigProcessor.process(RenderKitConfigProcessor.java:175)
 at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:110)
 at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ManagedBeanConfigProcessor.process(ManagedBeanConfigProcessor.java:266)
 at com.su ..... 
......
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
 at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.DomBasicRenderer.<clinit>(DomBasicRenderer.java:61)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
.....
Nov 2, 2010 10:04:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Nov 2, 2010 10:04:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/wtree-www] startup failed due to previous errors
```

I don't understand how copying the 4 files can generate this error. I haven't done anything else Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, the `caused by` part of the exception stacktrace tells about the root cause of the problem. In your case it's the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
```

This is pretty self-explaining. The mentioned class is missing in the runtime classpath. Add `commons-logging.jar` to `/WEB-INF/lib` and this particular problem should go. If you don't already have it somewhere else (in IceFaces download maybe?) then you can just get it at http://commons.apache.org/logging.